# MySQL returning not returning all the records

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I have two tables listed below:-

1. football - It has 2267 unique records.
2. football_assets - It has 2716 unique records.

Now I'm running following mysql query in phpmyadmin :-

```
select * from football_assets where pair in (SELECT DISTINCT pair FROM `football`);
```

The query returns only 2191 players but it should give 2267 records. I want to know why??

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should it give 2267 records? It's clear that there aren't 2267 matching pairs in football_assets/football.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT pair FROM `football`` will return 2716 pairs and when I'm checking `pair in` it will find match of those 2267 pairs.... right??

Comment: Wrong. The maximum records it could return is all the records in football_assets. If it return less then not all of the records are paired. BTW your last comment is the inverse of the question in terms of the numbers in the question.

Comment: @P.Salmon please explain the answer of my question....thank you

Answer (score 0):

The results you are getting show that there are 2267-2191 = 76 records in football_assets whose pair cannot be found in football.

You can exhibit these records by changing the IN in your query to NOT IN :

```
SELECT * 
FROM football_assets 
WHERE pair NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT pair FROM `football`
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the `select distinct` is redundant in the subquery.  A `WHERE` clause does not change the number of rows.  So, you should write:

```
select fa.*
from football_assets fa
where fa.pair in (select f.pair from football f);
```

Obviously, you have some pairs that are not in both tables.  I strongly encourage you to use `not exists` or `left join`/`where` to find them:

```
select fa.*
from football_assets fa
where not exists (select 1 from football f where fa.pair = f.pair);
```

Do not use `not in`.  It will return no rows at all if even a single value of `pair` is `NULL` in `football`.  That is because of how `NULL`s work in SQL.  For this reason, I strongly discourage `not in` with subqueries.